# Firebase return result of getDownloadURL

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I have a function that is first saving an image to Firebase and then getting back the download url. Right now I am able to get the `url` back (see `return url`), but I don't know how to return it for the function as a whole, since it is nested, and since this function runs asynchronously and will return the url empty if it has not been assigned before `getDownloadURL` has returned.

**Where function is called**

```
takePictureTemp() {
  var storedImg: any = this.usersale.submitImgTemp();
}
```

**/providers/usersale-data.ts**

```
submitImgTemp() {

    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    // Create a timestamp as filename
    const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    // Create a reference to 'images/todays-date.jpg'
    const imageRef: any = storageRef.child(`userImages/${filename}.jpg`);

    imageRef.putString("data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then((snapshot)=> {
        imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            return url;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle any errors here
            console.log(error);
        });
    });     

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having submitImgTemp() figure out what to do with the url, have the caller of submitImgTemp() handle what to do.

```
takePictureTemp() {
  this.usersale.submitImgTemp().then(d => {
    // d is your url
  }).catch(err => {})
}

submitImgTemp() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     // do your saving here
     // on successful save call resolve(url)
     // on error call reject(error)
  })
}
```

- I don't know what scopes are where so the basic idea here is do an sync call and when it's done, the caller can handle it in the then part.  The previous answer was wrong because I thought a subject was being return but it was Promise.
- You're calling async code so you have to handle accordingly by also making your call async since you don't know when the method will return.

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: this.usersale.submitImgTemp(...).subscribe is not a function`

Comment: Got it! Super helpful and definitely gave me a firmer grasp on promises/async. Thanks!